# How to write a listed pandas dataset into an excel xlsx file?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create an if statement for my listed dataset to check the conditions in the if statement and if it passes it should add the values from the dataset in the first already created and formated worksheet starting from row[2] and column[0] and if it does not pass it should add the values in the second already created and formated worksheet at the same row and column indeces

I have added two for loops to iterate through the data

```
import csv
import xlsxwriter
import pandas
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

with open(r'directory', 'r') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
newlist= list(spamreader)
#print(newlist)
#newlist = [['ï»¿id', 'name', 'lastContactedTime', 'email', 'phone_phones', 'home_phones', 'mobile_phones', 'work_phones', 'fax_phones', 'other_phones', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'address_3', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'country', 'tags'], ['15-contacts', 'Jane Doe', '', 'j@greenbriar.com', '', '+1 6570987234', '+1 3245687907', '+1 5678743546', '', '', '54 George street', '', '', 'Ridge Springs', 'VA', '25678', 'US', ''], ['3-contacts', 'Joe Malcoun', '2019-08-28 14:29:27', 'ceo@nutshell.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '212 South Fifth Ave', '', '', 'Ann Arbor', 'MI', '48103', 'US', ''], ['7-contacts', 'Morgan Ramirez', '', 'mramirez@nerdy.com', '', '', '+1 6780431874', '+1 3338765438', '+1 5679876987', '', '567 one st', '', '', 'Birmingham', 'AL', '45678', 'US', ''], ['11-contacts', 'Roman Burki', '', 'burki@bvb.com', '', '', '+1 0983457690', '+1 5468756098', '', '', '546 fourteen street Nw', '', '', 'Dallas', 'TX', '54678', 'US', '']]




# I have created two worksheets, formatted them (code not included but worksheet works and added words to the cells

workbook= xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test1.xlsx')
worksheet= workbook.add_worksheet()

workbook2= xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test2.xlsx')
worksheet2= workbook2.add_worksheet()
df = pd.DataFrame(newlist[1:], columns=newlist[0])
addresses = df.address_1.tolist()


df[['name', 'ï»¿id']] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand=True)

# rename id
df.rename(columns={'ï»¿id': 'Lastname','name': 'Firstname','lastContactedTime': 'Company','email':'Work_email', 'other_phones':'Personal_City', 'address_1':'Work_Street', 'address_2':'Personal_Zip', 'address_3':'Personal_Street', 'city':'Work_City', 'state':'Work_State', 'postal_code':'Work_Zip', 'tags':'Personal_email'}, inplace=True)

df[['Work_email', 'Company']] = df.Work_email.str.split('@', expand=True)

df.Company = [x.strip('.com') for x in df.Company]


del df['phone_phones']
note =  [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
df['Note'] = note


notecat =  [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
df['Note_Category'] = notecat

title =  [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
df['Title'] = title

Willingtoshare =  [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
df['Willing_to_share'] = Willingtoshare

Willingtointroduce =  [' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
df['Willing_to_introduce'] = Willingtointroduce

Personalstate =[' ', ' ', ' ',' ']
df['Personal_State'] = Personalstate

df[['country_code', 'work_phones']] = df.work_phones.str.split(' ', expand=True)
del df['country_code']
del df['country']
del df['fax_phones']
del df['home_phones']
#print(df)

  Lastname Firstname  ... Willing_to_introduce Personal_State
0      Doe      Jane  ...                                    
1  Malcoun       Joe  ...                                    
2  Ramirez    Morgan  ...                                    
3    Burki     Roman  ...                                    

[4 rows x 20 columns]
excel_file = IO()

df = df[['Lastname', 'Firstname','Company','Title','Willing_to_share','Willing_to_introduce','work_phones','Work_email','Work_Street','Work_City','Work_State','Work_Zip','Personal_Street','Personal_City','Personal_State','Personal_Zip','mobile_phones','Personal_email','Note','Note_Category']]
data=df.values.tolist()
columns=df.columns
sf=df.columns.tolist()

book = load_workbook('Test1.xlsx')
writer= pd.ExcelWriter('Test1.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') 
writer.book = book


book2 = load_workbook('Test2.xlsx')
writer2= pd.ExcelWriter('Test2.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
writer2.book2 = book2


workbook = writer.book
workbook2 = writer2.book2

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Sheet2']

value = data
for column in df:
   for col, sf in enumerate(data):
        if (column[0] != ' ' and column[1] != ' ') and ((column[2] != ' ' and column[3] != ' ') or (column[2] == ' ') and (column[6] != ' ') or (column[16] != ' ') and (column[12] != ' ' and column[13] != ' ' and column[14] != ' ' and column[15] != ' ') or (column[8] != ' ' and column[9] != ' ' and column[10] != ' ' and column[11] != ' ' and (column[7] != ' ' or column[17] != ' '))):
            worksheet.write('A3', value)
            #df.to_excel(writer, header = False, startcol=1, startrow=3)
        else:
            worksheet2.write('A3', value) 


writer.save()
writer.close()
writer2.save()
writer2.close()
workbook.close()
workbook2.close()
```

KeyError: 'Sheet1' and my expected output is it starts printing the data without the header starting from A3

Comment: what's wrong with `df.to_excel`?

Comment: what are you trying todo with that `if` statement? it is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Valid address must have street, city, state and zip 2) a valid contact must have first name, last name, and at least one phone, or address or email of any type (personal or work) 3) if a phone or email or address is not explicity identified as peronal/home or work, check if company or title exist, if either or both exist assume unlabled address or phone or email  are work related otherwise they are personal/home
Contacts which don't meet our criteria, create another excel file and dump them there.

Comment: I also want to start from the third row and I want to exclude the headers. I want to write the values only

Comment: you can do you all of that by 1) preparing your data frame and 2) using `df.to_excel`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I changed some of the code and the description I hope it is more reproducible now

Comment: It's not reproducible at all. Your dataframe is undefined.

Comment: The dataframe is from an imported CSV file. I cannot post it here

Comment: So post fake that that mimic it

Comment: (and show your expected output based on that fake data)

Comment: I have added the data and more about the expected result

Answer (score 0):

The way to edit existing worksheet

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open(r'C:/workbench/SemiFinale/train.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
   spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   newlist= list(spamreader)

df = pd.DataFrame(newlist[1:], columns=newlist[0])

# Creation of writer object 

writer= pd.ExcelWriter('Test1.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')

# This is first time creation and saving of file

df.to_excel(writer, header = False, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=5, startrow=10)  # startcol, startrow can be used in this condition
df.to_excel(writer, header = False, sheet_name='Sheet2', startcol=8, startrow=6)

#This is for reading of file, but first above code needs to be executed

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Sheet2']

value = "abc"
col_num = 10
worksheet1.write('A1', value)
workbook.close()


writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it gives me KeyError: 'Sheet1'. I will show you how my code looks now on the top post

Comment: @mos Issue is that you are trying to open worksheet which are not saved yet, I have updated above code with one that's running with comments

Comment: Do you think I can add formatting using writer? I will try to see if it is doable and I will get back to you

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open(r'C:/workbench/SemiFinale/train.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
   spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   newlist= list(spamreader)

df = pd.DataFrame(newlist[1:], columns=newlist[0])

writer= pd.ExcelWriter('Test1.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, header = False, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=1, startrow=10)  # startcol, startrow can be used in this condition
df.to_excel(writer, header = False, sheet_name='Sheet2', startcol=3, startrow=6)

# Above code successfully saves dataframe values in excel format
# And to satisfy your if condition you can use it as below format

# for column in df:
#    for col, sf in enumerate(data):
#       if (condition staisfied):
#          df.to_excel(writer, header = False, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=1, startrow=10)
#       else:
#          df.to_excel(writer, header = False, sheet_name='Sheet2', startcol=3, startrow=6)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: How can I include the for loop? in my code. Also it tells me D2 is not defined

Comment: @mos I have updated code, you can simply continue the conditions the way you want, I have added code how to save that in worksheet

Comment: Thanks @Amit Vashistha but I am still receiving a NameError: name 'A2' is not defined

Comment: @mos my bad, it has to be defined in quotes, try now.

Comment: Now I'm getting TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> in write()

Comment: @mos Please share the exact code that you are executing

Comment: @mos I have updated the answer with new code, since you are looking to save excel you can use above code. This is working code which is successfully saving excel sheet with defined starting row and column. Do let me know if you still face issue with it, else you can accept the answer

Comment: How can I edit the worksheets which were already created: worksheet and worksheet 2?